# How to maximize $\min_k a_k$ under constraints $\sum_k a_k=A$ and $\sum_k a_k^2=B$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I want to find the tuple of positive real numbers $a_k>0$ that maximize the cost $\min_k a_k$, under the constraints $\sum_k a_k=A$ and $\sum_k a_k^2=B$, for some given $A,B>0$. Assume $k=1,...,n$ for some $n$.

Normally, for this kind of problem, I'd use Lagrange multipliers, defining the Lagrangian
$$L = \min_k a_k + \alpha \left(\sum_k a_k-A\right) + \beta \left(\sum_k a_k^2-B\right),$$
and working out the conditions that come out imposing $\nabla L=0$. However, in this case, the $\min$ function defining the cost has a discontinuous derivative, which makes me unsure as to how to proceed.

---

For concreteness and better clarity, let's work out the $n=2$ case. The problem is here to find the max of $\min(a_1,a_2)$ under the given constraints. I'd then write the Lagrangian function
$$L = \min(a_1,a_2) + \alpha \left(\sum_{k=1}^2 a_k-A\right) + \beta \left(\sum_{k=1}^2 a_k^2-B\right) .$$
From this, imposing $\partial_{a_k}L=0$, we'd get the conditions $1+\alpha+2\beta a_1=0$ and $\alpha+2\beta a_2=0$, which can be solved for $\alpha,\beta$. But in this simple case, the constraints also directly impose the conditions $a_1+a_2=A$ and $a_1^2+a_2^2=B$, which can be directly solved to give
$$a_1^\pm = \frac{A}{2} \pm \frac12\sqrt{2B-A^2}, \qquad a_2 = A- a_1.$$
It's not hard to see from basic arithmetic considerations that $2B-A^2\ge0$, and thus $0\le a_1^-,a_2^- \le A/2$.
Thus we can always write $\min(a_1,a_2) = \frac A2 - \frac12\sqrt{2B-A^2}$, and that's the final answer, as here there's no room for further optimisation (and introducing the Lagrangian is effectively useless).

---

Let's try to tackle the slightly less boring case with $n=3$. Now the constraints don't automatically determine $a_1,a_2,a_3$. If I try to work out the problem with the simplified Lagrangian
$$L=a_1 + \alpha \left(\sum_{k=1}^3 a_k-A\right) + \beta \left(\sum_{k=1}^3 a_k^2-B\right),$$
imposing vanishing gradient I get the three conditions
$$\begin{cases}1+ \alpha + 2\beta a_1=0, \\
\alpha + 2\beta a_2 =0, \\
\alpha + 2\beta a_3 =0,\end{cases}$$
which imply $\beta(a_2-a_3)=0$ and $2\beta(a_3-a_1)=2\beta(a_2-a_1)=0$. Thus we must have $\beta\neq0$, which in turn implies $a_2=a_3$, and we go back to a situation where the constraints determine $a_1$, now via $a_1+2a_2=A$ and $a_1^2+2a_2^2=B$, which give
$$a_1^\pm = \frac{A}{3} \pm \frac{\sqrt2}{3}\sqrt{3B-A^2}.$$
This is more or less where I hit the problem: I'm tempted to say that, by symmetry, this tells me the stationary points for each individual variable $a_1,a_2,a_3$. But what I actually want is the stationary points (and in particular the max) for their min, and I'm not sure how to convert from one problem into the other using a relatively "elegant" argument (that is to say, possibly without having to work out a plethora of subcases to get there). Furthermore, I think the solutions obtained imposing $\nabla L=0$ (with the $L$ using $\min a_k$ as cost function) only tell me the local stationary points in regions where the cost is smooth (or at least is differentiable), so all regions corresponding to some $a_j=a_k$ are probably left out.

Answer (score 2):

In the case $n=3$ the command of Mathematica 13.3 (Capital letters as parameters and subscripts are not welcome in MMA.)

```
Maximize[{Min[a1, a2, a3],  a1 + a2 + a3 == a && 
a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == b && {a1, a2, a3} >= 0 && a > 0 &&  b > 0}, {a1, a2, a3}]
```

answers
$$ \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   \frac{a^2}{3}<b\leq a^2 \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   b=\frac{a^2}{3} \\
 -\infty  & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\left\{\text{a1}\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   \frac{a^2}{3}<b\leq a^2 \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   b=\frac{a^2}{3} \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\text{a2}\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} \left(a-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   b=\frac{a^2}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   \frac{a^2}{3}<b\leq a^2 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\text{a3}\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} \left(a+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   \frac{a^2}{3}<b\leq a^2 \\
 \frac{1}{6} \left(2 a+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3 b-a^2}\right) & a>0\land
   b=\frac{a^2}{3} \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: sure, I can get the solution with Mathematica (and you can further simplify it because here you know that $A,B>0$, $A^2\ge B$, and $A^2\le 3B$) , but that doesn't tell me the reasoning used to get there. From MMA's solutions you can tell that the max is achieved with all but one of the coefficients being equal to each other. In other words, it corresponds to one of the local solutions obtained via the reasoning outlined in the question via the simplified Lagrangian. But how do you argue analytically that this works?

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is fully symmetric, for any solution $a_{k}$ also any permutation of the tuple is also a solution of the minimizing problem. Therefore we can without loss of generalizazion transform the optimization problem doing the following:

$$
\begin{cases}
\max \min_{1\leq k\leq N} a_k\\
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k=A\\
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2=B \\
a_k>0 \quad 1\leq k\leq N
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\max a_1\\
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k=A\\
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2=B \\
a_1\leq a_k \quad 2\leq k\leq N\\
a_1>0
\end{cases}\\
$$

If we search for solutions of the latter problem we can tackle the first two constraints via lagrange multipliers and end up with:
$$L = a_1 + \alpha \left(\sum_{k=1}^N a_k-A\right) + \beta \left(\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2-B\right)$$
Now we check for critical points and see that
$$
0=\partial_{a_1}L=1+\alpha+2\beta a_1\\
0=\partial_{a_i}L=\alpha+2\beta a_i \quad 2\leq i \leq N\\
$$

Therefore we immediatly see that for a critical point $a_i=a_j$ for all $2\leq i,j \leq N$. Side note: we have not yet checked if the found critical points are actually within the admissible domain $0<a_1\leq a_i$ for $2\leq i\leq N$, but if there exists a critical point we now know it is of that form.
Evaluation of the contraints yields (similar to your $N=2$ case above)
$$
a_1=\frac{A \pm \sqrt{(N-1) (B N-A^2)}}{N}\\
a_i=\frac{A (N-1) \mp \sqrt{(N-1) (B N-A^2)}}{(N-1) N}\quad 2\leq i\leq N
$$
If we now demand that $a_1\leq a_i$ we easily see that only the lower solution remains, namely
$$
a_1=\frac{A - \sqrt{(N-1) (B N-A^2)}}{N}\\
a_i=\frac{A (N-1) + \sqrt{(N-1) (B N-A^2)}}{(N-1) N}\quad 2\leq i\leq N
$$
Additionaly restrictions for admissible critical points are
$$
BN\geq A^2 \text{ from the square root.}\\
A^2>B(N-1) \mbox{ from } a_1>0. 
$$
These two conditions are to be expected, since the sphere and the hyperplane do only intersect for $a_i>0$ for specific $A$ and $B$.

Unfortunately, as commenters pointed out, this does not yield the desired maximum. Therefore we need to investigate the boundaries of the domain, especially $a_1\leq a_k$. Since we do not know how many of the $a_k$ are equal to $a_1$ we can either do it step by step or we formulate it by introducing a new unkown $1\leq m\leq N$ and solve the following optimisation problem

$$
\begin{cases}
\max_{1\leq m\leq N}\max a_1\\
m\cdot a_1 + \sum_{k=m+1}^N a_k=A\\
m\cdot a_1^2 + \sum_{k=m+1}^N a_k^2=B \\
a_1< a_k \quad m+1\leq k\leq N\\
a_1>0
\end{cases}
$$

This yields (similar as above)
$$
a_1=\frac{A m - \sqrt{m (N-m) (B N-A^2)}}{m N}=\frac{A  - \sqrt{\tfrac{N-m}{m} (B N-A^2)}}{N}\\
a_k = \frac{A(N-m) + \sqrt{m (N-m) (B N-A^2)}}{N(N-m)}
$$

now if we investigate the $a_1$ we can easily see that it is maximized for $m$ as large as possible, but the constraints can no longer be fulfilled for $m=N$ so we achieve the maximum for$m=N-1$.

This yields finally
$$
\max\min a_k = a_1=\frac{A (N-1) - \sqrt{(N-1) (B N-A^2)}}{(N-1) N}
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, `Maximize[{a1, 
   a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 == a && 
    a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4^2 == b && {a1, a2, a3, a4} >= 0 && a > 0 &&
     b > 0 && a1 <= a2 && a1 <= a3, a1 <= a4}, {a1, a2, a3, 
   a4}] // FullSimplify` does not confirm it, resulting in

Comment: `{Piecewise[{{(3*a - Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])/12,    a > 0 && a^2 < 4*b && a^2 >= b}, {a/4, a > 0 && a^2 == 4*b}},   -Infinity],  {a1 -> Piecewise[{{(3*a - Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])/12,     a > 0 && a^2 < 4*b && a^2 >= b}, {a/4, a > 0 && a^2 == 4*b}},   Indeterminate], 
  a2 -> Piecewise[{{(3*a - Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])/12, 
      a > 0 && a^2 < 4*b && a^2 >= b}, {a/4, a > 0 && a^2 == 4*b}}, 
    Indeterminate],`

Comment: `a3 -> Piecewise[{{(3*a - Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])/12, 
      a > 0 && a^2 < 4*b && a^2 >= b}, {a/4, a > 0 && a^2 == 4*b}}, 
    Indeterminate], a4 -> Piecewise[{{a/4, a > 0 && a^2 == 4*b}, 
     {(a + Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-a^2 + 4*b])/4, a > 0 && a^2 < 4*b && 
       a^2 >= b}}, Indeterminate]}}`

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax, but it seems you have a comma before "a1<=a4" when you previously alwys put a &&? Additionally can you please post the achieved maximum?

Comment: I think this might fail because looking for local stationary points for $a_1$ via the Lagrangian, like I also tried, imposes that all other coefficients are equal to each other. However, it seems that the actual solution violates this assumption: you can get a larger min if you have a single *largest* value for $a_1$ and all other coefficients are the same. In other words, it appears you need to take the larger solution for $a_1$, in your calculation, so that all other coefficients are equal to each other and smaller than $a_1$. This at least checks out with the numerics

Comment: maybe your argument works by slightly generalising it: you optimise $a_1$; find two possible values, call them $a_1^\pm$, but you then still need to look for $\min a_k$, which is either $a_1^-$, or $(A-a_1^+)/(N-1)$. Looking explicitly at both the resulting expression, the latter is found to be the largest, hence the solution to the problem. This also seems to check out with the numerical solutions. I'm still not super fond of this argument though, it's a bit convoluted. I wonder if directly integrating the $a_1\le a_k$ condition into the Lagrangian gives a more direct route

Comment: Thanks for the comments that pointed out my mistake. It seems the maximum is indeed taken on the boundary $a_1\leq a_k$. I included an additional step to search for critical points on the boundary.

Comment: @glS as a remark: I tried to include the $a_1\leq a_k$ conditions in the lagrangian but was not able to solve the resulting equations.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a lagrangian as

$$
L(a,\lambda,s) = a_1+\lambda_0\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k - A\right)+\lambda_1\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2-B\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k+1}(a_k-s_k^2)\ \ \ \ (1)
$$

we arrive to a solution which agrees with the numerical solution for

$$
\max(\min a_k)\ \ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \ \cases{\sum_{k=1}^na_k = A\\ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2=B\\ a_k \ge 0}\ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which calculates the stationary points to the problem $(1)$ and verifies that between those stationary points, we can find the solution obtained thru the minimization of the problem $(2)$. The tests were realized using $A = 1, B = \frac 13$ such that $\frac{A^2}{n}\lt B\lt A^2$.

```
n = 7;
A = 1;
B = 1/3;
tA = Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}];
tL = Table[lambda[k], {k, 0, n + 1}];
tS = Table[s[k], {k, 1, n}];
L = a[1] + lambda[0] (Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] - A) + lambda[1] (Sum[a[k]^2, {k, 1, n}] - B) + Sum[lambda[k + 1] (a[k] - s[k]^2), {k, 1, n}];
vars = Join[Join[tA, tL], tS];
equs = Grad[L, vars];
sols = Quiet@Solve[equs == 0, vars];
vars2 = Join[Join[tA, tL], Table[s[k]^2, {k, 1, n}]];
res = Union[vars2 /. sols] // FullSimplify;
GOODS = {};
For[k = 1, k <= Length[res], k++, real = True; For[j = 1, j <= 3 n + 2, j++, If[NotElement[res[[k, j]], Reals] || ! NumericQ[res[[k,j]]], real = False]]; If[real, AppendTo[GOODS, res[[k]]]]]
res0 = Union[tA /. sols] // FullSimplify;
ineqA = Table[a[k] >= 0, {k, 1, n}];
NMaximize[Join[{Min[tA], Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] == A, Sum[a[k]^2, {k, 1, n}] == B}, ineqA], tA, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
For[k = 1; best = -10^10, k <= Length[GOODS], k++, 
 If[GOODS[[k, 1]] > best, kbest = k; best = GOODS[[k, 1]]]]
GOODS[[kbest]]
```

As we can verify in the last code line, $s_k^2=0\forall k$ as well as $\lambda_k=0,\ k= 2,\cdots, n$.

From $(1)$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 a(1) & a(2) & a(3) & a(4) & a(5) & a(6) & a(7) & \lambda (0) & \lambda (1) & \lambda (2) & \lambda (3) & \lambda (4) & \lambda (5)
   & \lambda (6) & \lambda (7) & \lambda (8) & s(1)^2 & s(2)^2 & s(3)^2 & s(4)^2 & s(5)^2 & s(6)^2 & s(7)^2 \\
 \frac{1}{7} \left(1+2 \sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21}
   \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21}
   \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{14} \left(3 \sqrt{2}-2\right) & -\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &
   \frac{1}{7} \left(1+2 \sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) &
   \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) & \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) &
   \frac{1}{21} \left(3-\sqrt{2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

From $(2)$

$$
\{0.0755136,\{a(1)\to 0.0755136,a(2)\to 0.0755136,a(3)\to 0.0755136,a(4)\to 0.0755136,a(5)\to 0.0755136,a(6)\to 0.0755136,a(7)\to
   0.546918\}\}
$$

Comment: thanks. What's $s_k$ here though? what's the rationale?

Comment: $s_k$ is a slack variable to include $a_k\ge 0$ into the lagrangian. $a_k-s_k^2=0\Leftrightarrow a_k\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a simple solution*:

Assume that $n \ge 3$. The problem is feasible if and only if $nB \ge A^2 > B$ and $A, B > 0$.

The maximum of $\min\limits_{1\le k\le n} a_k$ is given by
$$\frac{A}{n} - \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)}.$$
(*Note*: $\frac{A}{n} - \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)} > 0$.)

**Proof**.

WLOG, assume that $a_1 = \min(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$.

First, we have $\frac{A}{n} - a_1 \ge 0$ and
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\frac{A}{n} - a_1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)}\right)^2\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{n(n-1)a_1^2 - 2(n-1)Aa_1 + A^2 - B}{n(n - 1)}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{2}{n(n - 1)}\sum_{2 \le i < j \le n} (a_i - a_1)(a_j - a_1)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
which results in
$$\frac{A}{n} - \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)} \ge a_1.$$

Second, when
$$a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_{n-1} = \frac{A}{n} - \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)}$$
and
$$a_n = \frac{A}{n} + \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n},$$
we have $a_k > 0, \forall k$ and
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = A$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 = B$.

Thus, the maximum of $\min\limits_{1\le k\le n} a_k$ is given by
$$\frac{A}{n} - \frac{\sqrt{(n - 1)(nB - A^2)}}{n(n - 1)}.$$

We are done.

Comment: this is a nice way to verify the optimality of the solution, but you need to already know the expression somehow, right? Or do you have a way you might have guessed the term $\sqrt{(n-1)(nB-A^2)}/(n(n-1))$ without seeing the other solutions?

Comment: First, we can guess that the maximum occurs when $n-1$ of them are equal. This is a rational quess. For many inequality problems in MSE or AoPS), we guess that the optimum occurs when some of the variables are equal. The famous "Equal Variable Theorem" deals with when this is the case, although is not directly applied here.

Comment: Second, if we don't guess, we can use calculus (like other answers) to motivate the solution, however, while we used calculus to motivate our solution, we do not need to include any calculus in the solution! So we can write a simple solution based on the solution by calculus.

Comment: By the way, I used Equal variable theorem many times, e.g., [P1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4065609/find-this-least-postive-real-a/4100286#4100286]), [P2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025871/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-frac1a-sum-limits-cyc-frac11a2-geq-fr/3870471#3870471), [P3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281451/find-the-minumum-of-the-value-k-such-two-condition-x-1x-2-cdots-x-k-frac/3267179#3267179), [P4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594588/upper-bound-on-ratio-of-probability-sums/4594912#4594912).

Comment: Also, in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633085/bounds-on-max-i-p-i-in-terms-of-sum-i-p-i2/4635453#4635453), I guess that $n-1$ of the variables are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full "straightforward" way to solve the problem, using the idea from some of the other answers to introduce slack variables (which of course, a posteriori, is the standard approach in this context).

To avoid dealing with the non-smooth cost function, we instead consider $a_1$ as cost function, introducing the inequality constraints $a_1 \le a_k$ for all $k>1$. These inequality constraints are then converted into equality constraints introducing additional slack variables $s_k$. The Lagrangian thus becomes:
$$L = a_1 + \alpha\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-a\right) + \beta\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 -b\right) + \sum_{k=2}^n \gamma_k (a_k - a_1 - s_k^2),$$
where we have to remember that the task is now to minimise $a_1$ with respect to the variables $(a_1,...,a_n,s_2,...,s_n)$.

The gradient $\nabla L=0$ gives the conditions:
$$
1 + \alpha + 2\beta a_1 - \sum_{k=2}^n \gamma_k = 0, \\
\alpha + 2\beta a_k  + \gamma_k = 0, \qquad \forall k=2,..., n, \\
\gamma_k s_k=0, \qquad \forall k=2,..., n.
$$

---

Consider first the simplest case with $n=3$. We have several possibilities:

1. If $s_2,s_3\neq0$, then $\gamma_2=\gamma_3=0$. The conditions above then simplify to $$1+\alpha + 2\beta a_1=0, \quad \alpha + 2\beta a_2 = \alpha+ 2\beta a_3=0.$$
   This implies $a_2=a_3\neq a_1$. Using the constraints, we then find two possible solutions for $a_1$. One of these is larger than $a_2$, and is therefore excluded, and the remaining solution is $$a_1=\frac a3-\frac{\sqrt2}{3} \sqrt{3b-a^2}.$$
2. Suppose now $s_2=0$ and $s_3\neq0$. This means $a_1=a_2<a_3$. Then we can again directly use the constraints, finding two possible solutions for $a_1$, the smallest of which satisfies the constraints and equals
   $$a_1 = \frac{a}{3} - \frac{\sqrt2}{6}\sqrt{3b-a^2}.$$
   The case $s_2\neq0, s_3=0$ gives an identical solution.
3. The last possibility is having $s_2=s_3=0$. This implies $a_1=a_2=a_3$ and thus $a_1=a/3$. Due to the quadratic constraint, this is possible only if $3b=a^2$.

By direct inspection of the above three cases, the largest $a_1$ is clearly achieved (2) (which is identical to (3) when $3b=a^2$. We conclude that the max of $\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ is
$$a_1 = \frac a3-\frac{\sqrt2}{6}\sqrt{3b-a^2}.$$

---

Strong of the intuition provided by the above, let's tackle the general case $n>3$. Let's explore the possible scenarios as follows:

1. Suppose $s_k=0$ for all $k=2,...,n$. Then $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$, hence $a_1=a/n$. This is only possible if $nb=a^2$.
2. Suppose $s_2=...=s_{n-1}=0$ and $s_n\neq0$. Then $a_1=a_2=...=a_{n-1}<a_n$. The constraints then read $(n-1) a_1 + a_n=a$ and $(n-1)a_1^2+a_n^2=b$, which give two solutions, one of which corresponds to $a_1>a_n$ and is thus not feasible, and the other one is $$a_1 = \frac an - \frac{\sqrt{(n-1)(bn-a^2)}}{n(n-1)}.$$
3. Suppose more generally $s_1=...=s_m=0$, and $s_{m+1},...,s_n\neq0$, for some $1<m<n$. This implies $\gamma_{m+1}=...=\gamma_n=0$, and thus the corresponding conditions from $\nabla L=0$ become $\alpha+2\beta a_{m+1}=...=\alpha+2\beta a_n=0$. This implies $a_{m+1}=...=a_n$, and we yet again reach a situation with only two possible values for the $a_k$, namely, $a_1=...=a_m$ and $a_{m+1}=...=a_n$, but $a_1\neq a_n$. Using the constraints as always then gives the conditions $m a_1 + (n-m) a_n=a$ and $m a_1^2+(n-m)a_n^2=b$, which gives two solutions for $a_1$, the smallest of which is feasible and reads
   $$a_1 = \frac an - \frac{\sqrt{m(n-m)(bn-a^2)}}{nm}.$$

The above covers all possible situations. We now simply observes that $\sqrt{m(n-m)}/m$ decreases with $1< m <n$,  to conclude that the largest $a_1$ corresponds to case (2) above, and thus the final solution is
$$ a_1 = \frac an - \frac{\sqrt{(n-1)(bn-a^2)}}{n(n-1)}.$$